# How to replace the Text value with another string inside SelectListItem or SelectList mvc3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

Anyone can please tell me how can I replace the `Text` inside `SelectListItem`  or`SelectList`  list in mvc3. 
Suppose I have a selectlistitem which contains A and B as its `Text` values along with some other text values. Now what I am trying to do it to just replace these A and B Text values with X and Y. 
Although I will welcome any solution which will meet my requirement but solution using linq would be great.

Comment: When do you want to change these values? On some user action ?

Comment: please post ur code and where u want to implement this code

Comment: @Siddhath, Nitin thanks your valuable time. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer of my question. All though I am not able to replace the text in same list but what I have done is created a new selectlistitem and replaced the text there.

```
List<SelectListItem> listService = Model.ServiceTypeList.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.Text.Replace("A", "X").Replace("A", "X"), Value = Convert.ToString(x.Value) }).Cast<SelectListItem>().ToList();
```

But still if you have a better approach then you are welcome to share with me.